# Adding On Click event to Joomla menu with mootools

Tags: joomla, google-analytics, mootools

I am working on a joomla 1.5 site. I have been asked to add oclick events to the top level nav for google event tracking like so

I can't see anyway to do this in the joomla admin. I know in jquery I could use the append command to add it but not sure how to add this with mootools.

can somebody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the class of the elements in the top level nav, then u could do something very easy like:

```
window.addEvent('domready', function(){ //when the DOM is ready

  $$('.class-name').addEvent('click', function(evt){
    /* your event tracking, knowing that 'this' is the current .class-name element */  
  }); 

});
```

Comment: you're welcome ;) p.s. ..if you find that an answer is correct, please vote it and mark it as 'accepted', ty ;)